# How to check if the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n\cdot \sin(\frac{1}{n})$ is convergent

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

or divergent? $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n\cdot \sin(\frac{1}{n})$$
Which test I should use?

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: $\sin \frac{1}{n} \ge \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{n}$ for $n \ge 1$.

Comment: @copper.hat - How can you know that?

Comment: For $x \in [0,1]$ the Taylor series for $\sin$ gives a convenient upper bound $\sin x \ge x -\frac{1}{3} x^3 = x(1-\frac{1}{3} x^2) \ge \frac{2}{3} x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sine function has slope $1$ where it crosses the axis at the origin.  Therefore it lies above the line $y=\frac12 x$ if $x$ is positive but close to $0$.  Therefore
$$
\sin\frac1n > \frac12\cdot\frac1n.
$$
(At least if $n$ is big enough to make $\frac1n$ close enough to $0$.  But in this case $n=1$ is already big enough.)  So if
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\cdot\frac12\cdot\frac1n
$$
diverges, then so does your sum.

Answer (score 2):

What is $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin n^{-1}}{n^{-1}}\;?$$ Is it zero?

Comment: How do I calculate this? I should use one of the tests...

Comment: @YoavFridman Do you know anything about $$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\sin t}t ?$$

Comment: @YoavFridman How you calculate $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \dfrac{\sin x}{x}$ ? And you know that if $\sum a_n$ converge then $a_n \to 0$, think about it. ($p \implies q \iff \neg q \implies \neg p$) There is no need for test in this example.

Answer (score 1):

$\sin(x)$ is concave on $[0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$. That is to say, it lies above the line segment connecting $0$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Applying this we have that $\sin(x) \ge \frac{2}{\pi} x$  on this region.

since every $\frac{1}{n}$ in this region we have $\sin(\frac{1}{n}) \ge \frac{2}{\pi n}$.

Can you continue from here?

Comment: I hope so... As I understand, the series diverges.
But if I'm continue at your way I get the opposite result...
Can tell me what to do next?

Comment: You shouldn't get the opposite result! What you have here implies that $n \sin(\frac{1}{n}) \ge \frac{2}{\pi}$ and if you just sum $\frac{2}{\pi}$ infinitely many times you get infinity!